# resttemplate.getforObject(url,pojo.class) getting null in java 11, but it fetch data in java 1.8

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, java-11

```
String url = "http://********";

rt = restTemplate.getForObject(url, pojoObj.getClass());
```

It works fine in 1.8, but when I change the compiler to Java 11 it throws an error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http//******": localhost; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost
```

Comment: issue resolved..
i added this comments in host file
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 ::1             localhost